# How to make a comment sign not a comment sign

Tags: java, comments

Really quick question.
In java when commenting you can use "//" but how do I use "//" without wanting it to be a comment.

I have to write a URL and it's like "http://...". What do I add to make it not a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable while using `//` in your string literal already accomplishes this goal.

For example, you can declare a variable like this.

```java
String url = "https://www.google.com";
```

It is also valid to use the string literal `"//"`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to write a URL and it's like `"http://..."`.  What do I add to make it not a comment?

Nothing.  It is *already* not a comment!

Inside Java String literals, `//`, `/*` and `*/` have no special meaning.  They are just characters.  They do not denote the start of a comment:

```
String url = "https://not.a.comment";  // ... but this is a comment.
System.out.println(url);               // prints 'https://not.a.comment'
```

---

As [JLS 3.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7) states:

> *The lexical grammar implies that comments do not occur within character literals (§3.10.4) or string literals (§3.10.5).*